# jQuery 1.2.6 Build HTML Elements In Memory?

Tags: jquery, html, memory

I am using jQuery 1.2.6 to build up HTML elements in memory.  The image below [alt text http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/6026/jquerybuildobjects.png](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/6026/jquerybuildobjects.png)is a snippet of how I am doing it.  When I profile the HTML that is generated, below is what I am seeing.  Why is this happening?  What about my jQuery is incorrect here?[alt text http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/5760/jqueryhtml.png](http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/5760/jqueryhtml.png)

Comment: Why didn't you just copy & paste your code instead of screenshots?

Comment: Your comment has nothing to do with a solution to my problem...

Comment: What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Replace your screenshots with actual code and describe what the problem with that output is and people would probably be much more motivated to take a crack at it.

Comment: I mean it was more so, "Hey has anyone seen anything like this before?  It should be a pretty obvious thing I would think and I would assume someone must have seen something like this before...

Comment: Nowhere do you mention what exactly you are questioning. I'm glad galambalazs is enough of a psychic to answer an unclear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is creating **unique ids** for your elements. This is **not a bug**. It is **for storing data** with the [**data()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function.